# How to combine Two Recycler adapter into one Custom Adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, parallax, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I need to use two libraries for my Adapter, both Adapters are for different purpose, and i need to use them for my layout, one is `ParallaxRecyclerAdapter` and the other is `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is there a way to combine the two into one Custom Adapter?

Currently, I have using a custom `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, but I need `ParallaxRecyclerAdapter` too.

```
public class VendorNewAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NewsPaper, NewsPaperHolder>{



private  boolean isColorsInverted = false;
private Context context;
private AppCompatActivity activity;

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private Query oneQuery;
private DatabaseReference childRef;

public VendorNewAdapter(Class<NewsPaper> modelClass, int modelLayout,
                        Class<NewsPaperHolder> viewHolderClass, Query ref, AppCompatActivity activity,
                        boolean isViewWithList, Context context) {
    super(modelClass, modelLayout, viewHolderClass, ref);
    this.context = context;
    this. activity = activity;
    this.isColorsInverted = isViewWithList;
}


@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(final NewsPaperHolder viewHolder, NewsPaper model, int position) {

    viewHolder.vendorName.setText(model.getPaper_name());

    mDatabaseRef.child("news").orderByChild("newspaper_id").equalTo(oneChildRef).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}

}
```

Comment: What is the extra ParallaxRecyclerAdapter doing?

Comment: @Avi A parallax Scroll with an HeaderView

Comment: You can create an Adapter by extending FirebaseRecyclerAdapter which provide the same behavior as ParallaxRecyclerAdapter doing.

Comment: @Avi the ParallaxRecyclerAdapter is a library

Comment: You can use this CustomAdapter library:

  https://github.com/afollestad/sectioned-recyclerview

Comment: @vishalpatel my issue is combining two different library adapters into one

Comment: Th library is open source you can use its code.

Comment: In your case only extension can help composition won't work for you

Comment: @Avi i wish i know a little more about java, i would have used the code from the library, its just two classes, but most of the methods are abstract